# How to get the function to be computed differently for different values of x?

Tags: image-processing, halide

```
    Func support("support");

    Expr left_x = clamp(x, 0, left_buffer.width() / 4);
    RDom scan_left(0, left_buffer.width() / 4, 0, left_buffer.height());
    scan_left.where(scan_left.x != left_x && scan_left.y != y);
    support(x, y) = argmin(abs(output_x(left_x, y) - output_x(scan_left.x, scan_left.y)) + abs(output_y(left_x, y) - output_y(scan_left.x, scan_left.y)));

    Expr center_x = clamp(x, left_buffer.width() / 4, left_buffer.width() * 3/4);
    RDom scan_center(-left_buffer.width() / 4, left_buffer.width() / 2, 0, left_buffer.height());
    scan_center.where(scan_center.x != 0 && scan_center.y != 0);
    support(x, y) = argmin(abs(output_x(center_x, y) - output_x(center_x + scan_center.x, scan_center.y)) + abs(output_y(center_x, scan_center.y) - output_y(center_x + scan_center.x, scan_center.y)));

    Expr right_x = clamp(x, left_buffer.width() * 3/4, left_buffer.width());
    RDom scan_right(left_buffer.width() * 3/4, left_buffer.width() / 4, 0, left_buffer.height());
    scan_right.where(scan_right.x != right_x && scan_right.y != y);
    support(x, y) = argmin(abs(output_x(right_x, y) - output_x(scan_right.x, scan_right.y)) + abs(output_y(right_x, y) - output_y(scan_right.x, scan_right.y)));

    support.trace_stores();

    Realization r = support.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
```

The function "support" should be computed differently depending on the x value. For x = [0, width/4] compute it according to the first definition, for x = [width/4, width * 3/4] compute it according to the second definition, and for x = [width*3/4, width]  compute it according the third definition. I would think that putting the boundary conditions with respect to those update definitions and then realizing over the whole buffer would do the trick. Right now though, the previous definitions are being overwritten. Since this doesn't seem to work, I would think of doing three realizations but that seems inelegant since we're talking about just one image. Is it possible to achieve the result in a single realization, or must I break into three realizations?
I tried RDoms too:

```
Func support("support");
    support(x, y) = Tuple(i32(0), i32(0), f32(0));

    RDom left_x(0, left_buffer.width() / 4);
    RDom scan_left(0, left_buffer.width() / 4, 0, left_buffer.height());
    scan_left.where(scan_left.x != left_x && scan_left.y != y);
    support(left_x, y) = argmin(scan_left, abs(output_x(left_x, y) - output_x(scan_left.x, scan_left.y)) + abs(output_y(left_x, y) - output_y(scan_left.x, scan_left.y)));

    RDom center_x(left_buffer.width() / 4, left_buffer.width() / 2);
    RDom scan_center(-left_buffer.width() / 4, left_buffer.width() / 2, 0, left_buffer.height());
    scan_center.where(scan_center.x != 0 && scan_center.y != 0);
    support(center_x, y) = argmin(scan_center, abs(output_x(center_x, y) - \
    output_x(center_x + scan_center.x, scan_center.y)) + abs(output_y(center_x, scan_center.y) - \
    output_y(center_x + scan_center.x, scan_center.y)));

    RDom right_x(left_buffer.width() * 3/4, left_buffer.width() / 4);
    RDom scan_right(left_buffer.width() * 3/4, left_buffer.width() / 4, 0, left_buffer.height());
    scan_right.where(scan_right.x != right_x && scan_right.y != y);
    support(right_x, y) = argmin(scan_right, abs(output_x(right_x, y) - output_x(scan_right.x, scan_right.y)) + abs(output_y(right_x, y) - output_y(scan_right.x, scan_right.y)));

    support.compute_root();
    support.trace_stores();

    Realization r_left = support.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
```

but this code gives errors in the following lines:

```
scan_left.where(scan_left.x != left_x && scan_left.y != y);
...
scan_right.where(scan_right.x != right_x && scan_right.y != y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve this problem would be to use Halide's select method (example given [here](https://halide-lang.org/docs/tutorial_2lesson_13_tuples_8cpp-example.html)). Something like this should work:

```
Func support("support");

Expr left_x = clamp(x, 0, left_buffer.width() / 4);
RDom scan_left(0, left_buffer.width() / 4, 0, left_buffer.height());
scan_left.where(scan_left.x != left_x && scan_left.y != y);
Expr first = argmin(abs(output_x(left_x, y) - output_x(scan_left.x, scan_left.y)) + abs(output_y(left_x, y) - output_y(scan_left.x, scan_left.y)));

Expr center_x = clamp(x, left_buffer.width() / 4, left_buffer.width() * 3/4);
RDom scan_center(-left_buffer.width() / 4, left_buffer.width() / 2, 0, left_buffer.height());
scan_center.where(scan_center.x != 0 && scan_center.y != 0);
Expr second = argmin(abs(output_x(center_x, y) - output_x(center_x + scan_center.x, scan_center.y)) + abs(output_y(center_x, scan_center.y) - output_y(center_x + scan_center.x, scan_center.y)));

Expr right_x = clamp(x, left_buffer.width() * 3/4, left_buffer.width());
RDom scan_right(left_buffer.width() * 3/4, left_buffer.width() / 4, 0, left_buffer.height());
scan_right.where(scan_right.x != right_x && scan_right.y != y);
Expr third = argmin(abs(output_x(right_x, y) - output_x(scan_right.x, scan_right.y)) + abs(output_y(right_x, y) - output_y(scan_right.x, scan_right.y)));

int width = left_buffer.width();
# select based on x value
support(x, y) = select(x < width / 4, first, x < width * 3 / 4, second, third);

support.trace_stores();

Realization r = support.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
```

`

Comment: actually the line ```Expr first...``` gives ```error: conversion from 'Halide::Tuple' to non-scalar type 'Halide::Expr' requested```

Comment: The thing what I'm trying to do is that ```support``` is actually a 3d Tuple that must store the coordinates and also the value. So after the definition of support I should add ```support(x, y) = Tuple(i32(0), i32(0), f32(0));``` which I did. I fixed the error with the Tuple to Expr conversion by indexing the value using [2] after the argmin. But when doing ```support(x, y) = select( ...``` I want to get the whole Tuple and not just the value in index [2], and store these in ```support```.